# Laravel - Serving files based on user session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to create an app where there will be several videos teaching html and css, so any user can watch any video if authenticated.

For each user the url of these videos should be associated with the user session, preventing the user from sending the video url to others to (free) access.

When the user logof the `possible copy` of the file will be deleted with the user's session.

1. When a teacher uploads a video, the video will be saved with the
   storage system.
2. Create a copy of the file or make an association in database?
3. My thinking on how to handle these files is correct?

Any idea in how to do this?

Comment: Do not copy the video. I'm thinking that you can have a many to many relationship between users and videos, where it dictates what videos a user can only watch. Even if they send a url of the video, if the person who will open the url is not authenticated or not authorized to watch that video, then that person will not be able to access the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the video is embedded, but you also don't want the video link to be pulled from the source, I would suggest that you go with a basic approach.

If all users have access to all videos, then maintaining a mapping in the database is a bad idea. That would get huge, very quickly. It's also un-necessary.

You could add part to the end of your route, lets say something like;

```
$router->get('/watch/{videoId}/{userId}', [....]);
```

And then something like;

```
$router->get('/video/{videoId}/{userId}, [....]);
```

The first would be the route for the page where you watch the video, the second a dynamic link that you use to embed the video. All you need to do now is add some middleware that does something like the following;

```
if ($router->param('userId') !== auth()->id()) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

Alternative, you could do the above, but the routes would have `{videoId}/{videoHash}` instead of `{videoId}/{userId}`. The video hash would just be something like the following;

```
$videoHash = crc32($video->id . ';' . auth()->id);
```

Then, you just have middleware like the above, but instead, it does the following;

```
$hash = crc32($router->param('videoId') . ';' . auth()->id());
if ($router->param('videoHash') !== $hash) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

The second option is a bit overcomplicated, but it may 'look a bit better'. Either way is a hundred times simpler than using a database.

Comment: I really enjoyed your answer, in fact, putting this in the database after a while can give me some kind of headache... Thanks for the reply, I'll implement it

Comment: I respect this answer, but it does not handling user based restrictions for file. Eg, how you are know user have access to that file(before showing video in page)?. This answer only moves user mapping check from file route to the page displaying it. You still need Many-Many mapping.

Comment: @CaioKawasaki glad I could help. It really doesn't make sense to put it in the database.

Comment: @JithinJose You're mistaken, and have misunderstood the question. There is no user video restriction `so any user can watch any video if authenticated.`

Comment: I dont understand all the razmataz. I mean if any authenticated user can watch it, why not keep the route as simple as `/video/{videoId}` and add the `auth` middleware. What's with the jazz?

Comment: I don't really know, it does seem a little strange. That being said, there may be a good reason for it. I've seen stranger.

Comment: @Paras, I agree with your point, if only need to check user is authenticated or not, why need to use user_id and hash?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware). Create a table that stores which user has access to what video. The middleware can check if the user logged in has access to the video requested. If not `abort(403)`.

The URL would be the same for all users, say `/videos/{video_id}` but only the users granted access can watch the video because of the middleware

Answer (score 0):

I will divide your problem into two parts

- Make video content assignable to authenticated users
- Prevent all authenticated  users to share the content outside the current session

**First**

'many-to-many' relation between uploaded content and users 

`users -> video_user <- videos` 
 
`$user->allowedVideos()` & `$video->allowedUsers()`

**Second**

your video content should be accessible through a secure route

`{base_url}/video/{video_id}`

as @jithin suggesting, we can use a `middleware`  to authorize the user login session and check if the video is accessible to user. Else return 403.

-- Answer is updated

Comment: Y need to have session id or token in url? We can use session id in cookie right as similar to other requests?

Comment: oh i see, yes @jithin you are absolutely right. We should use COOKIE to authorize and remove the token part from url .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to implement access restriction for files. So as suggested by @Farooq Khan, implement a pivot table to hold user-file mappings to find who have access to those files.

Next step will be authenticating file url. File url will be same for all users, one example will be `/admin/download/{fileName}`. Please not the file will not actually exists in `/admin/download/` directory, so request will be redirected to laravel by web server.

```
Route::get('/admin/download/{file_name}', ['as' => 'admin.download', function($fileName) 
{
    return Response::download($file_name);
}])->before('file_auth');
```

Now you have to create file_auth middleware, in which you have to check user (`Auth::user()->id`) have access to filename (`$request->route('fileName')`). If user does not have permission respond with 403.